# Oracle error "M_ROW$$": invalid identifier when restoring a materialized view

Tags: database, oracle, materialized-views

I tried to restore a materialized view in my DB by using the sql script. The view is correctly created but the script has failed when creating the index.
There the sql issue:

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "APP"."I_SNAP$_APP_HIST_LIB_OR1" ON "APP"."APP_HIST_LIB_ORGANES_MV" ("M_ROW$$") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "APP_DATA" ;
```

The issue:

```
ORA-00904: "M_ROW$$": invalid identifier
```

I don't know what is "M_ROW$$".

After looking on forums, the reason should be that this identifier is not present in the table
but present in the mview log. But I don't have access to mview log.

Could you please confirm me that or tell me how to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: "I tried to restore a materialized view in my DB by using the sql script" What script? Seems like your script is wrong if it's trying to create an index on the materialized view using a column that's only in the materialized view log.

Comment: I don't put the complete script in the ticket because it doesn't help. It works for creating the materialised view APP_HIST_LIB_ORGANES_MV. Nothing in this script for creating this materialized view is related to "M_ROW$$" (there is no field named "M_ROW$$" in the view). Just the query for creating the index (last row of the script) failed (code in this topic).

Comment: So your script is wrong? You need to find out who wrote it and why they wrote it like that.

Comment: Sorry but the script cannot be wrong because I done directly my-self an export of the view from the database 2 days ago with the tool SQL Developer. That's why I don't understand this kind of index.

Comment: so perhaps there’s a bug in the SQL Developer export? Did that index really exist before on the mview?

Comment: no - so in order to avoid issue I didn't create this index

Comment: you would need to provide the full details to recreate the issue. What were the indexes on the mview before you generated the script? What weee the columns in your mview? Etc.